# Is the `inline` prop incompatible with `SVGTooltip`?

Tags: blueprintjs

Trying to render an SVGTooltip inline, and it appears the html is not being rendered inside of the SVG. Is this an issue of prop incompatibility? I've viewed the source of the tooltip and it consists of spans, divs, and other html elements, can these not be drawn inside of SVG without using the foreignObject tag as a parent?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, `inline` is incompatible with `SVGTooltip` because it uses HTML tags that are invalid in an SVG context. Regular (non-inline) `SVGTooltip` works because it only needs to render one element inline `<g>` and the rest is rendered in a portal.

The component should probably log a console warning about this incompatibility, or the docs should be updated to mention it.

Comment: Would it be possible to implement the `SVGTooltip` with an `inline` property that is functional by use of `foreignObject` tags? https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/embedded.html